# Searching composite aggregations in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Take a look at this code:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
        "match" : {
            "productName" : "A product name"
        }
   }

  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_buckets": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          { "_id": {"terms": {"field": "supplierId"}}},
          { "supplierTitle": {"terms": {"field": "supplierTitle"}}}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What this does is: looks up all the items with productName fields that match the query and from these items it makes facets using the item's _id and supplierTitle properties. So the result tells the count of combinations that consist of a certain _id and certain supplierTitle (number of items with this combination). Now the question is how could I filter/search these facets so instead of returning all facets it returns only the facets with a supplierTitle that is wanted by the user (it would be great if I could run a custom match query on the supplierTitle field). Any suggestion? I have been researching this for some time but without much success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter supplier in query itself using must clause.

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "productName.keyword": "abc"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "supplierTitle": "s1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_buckets": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "_id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "supplierId"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "supplierTitle": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "supplierTitle.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

composite aggregation cannot be used as sub aggregation. You can use [multi-terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-multi-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-multi-terms-aggregation) aggregation which is available in latest version

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "productName.keyword": "abc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "filter_supplier": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "supplierTitle.keyword": "s1"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_buckets": {
          "multi_terms": {
            "terms": [
              {
                "field": "supplierId"
              },
              {
                "field": "supplierTitle.keyword"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I am curious however about the second query example: instead of a simple filter by term, could I perhaps use a more complex search (like searching by substrings, supplierTitle would have to be text type)?

Comment: Filter aggregation supports other queries like match , wildcard etc you can try this  "filter": {
        "wildcard": {
          "supplierTitle": {
            "value": "s*"
          }
        }
      }

Comment: Is there a possibility of a scored search inside aggregations? So that when you use query and match with multiple words the facet with the most correct words becomes the first that is present in the results?

Comment: Filter context doesn't score document. It just includes or excludes a document. I think problem can be best solved by filtering docs in query part